# Socket Programming. issue with connect(...) api

Tags: c++, winapi, sockets, networking, network-programming

In my network programming project (in visual C++), I am facing one problem with connect(...) api. The code segment for connect() is as below.

```
if (connect(sockfd[0], &sock.addr, sizeof(sock.inaddr)) == SOCKET_ERROR){
    wprintf(L"connect function failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(sockfd[0]);
    WSACleanup();
}
```

for above mentioned code i am getting follwoing compilation error, which doesn't make sense as connect should take 3 args.

```
error C2660: 'SampleClass::connect' : function does not take 3 arguments
```

Can anyone help me to figure out what i am missing here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to call a class member connect. Prefix the connect with :: so it finds the correct function.

```
if (::connect(sockfd[0], &sock.addr, sizeof(sock.inaddr)) == SOCKET_ERROR){
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your class has its *own* `connect` method, try calling `::connect` instead, which should give you the 'standard' one.